# language translation in Selenium java

Tags: selenium

I am Trying to translate the webpage with following code but it did not work.

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.addArguments("start-maximized");
        option.addArguments("test-type");
        option.addArguments("--lang=en-US");
        option.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        option.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.staffers.no/jobbsoker");
```

Comment: that page is in English, in which language you want to translate ?

Comment: This is in Norwegian. I want to translate in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code :

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("start-maximized");
option.addArguments("test-type");
 
option.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
option.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", true);


Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> langs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
langs.put("no", "en");
prefs.put("translate", "{'enabled' : true}");
prefs.put("translate_whitelists", langs);
option.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);

driver.get("https://www.staffers.no/jobbsoker");
```