# How to change webpage language from English to others in Edge using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge, bing-translator-api

I know how to change languages in selenium. You will say:

```
options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
prefs = {
        "translate_whitelists": {'fr':'en'},
        "translate":{"enabled":"true"}}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = Edge(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
```

This works fine for all types of language but when i try to change from english to another language it doesnt work. For example:

```
prefs = {
        "translate_whitelists": {'en':'es'},
        "translate":{"enabled":"true"}}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

But if i say `"translate_whitelists": {'es':'fr'},` 
It works. Basically you can convert to any output language but if the input language is english it doesnt work. Please help and explain

Comment: try this `"translate_whitelists": {'en-GB':'es'}`

Comment: I tryed it it didnt work

Comment: okay can you check the same in chrome browser once  ? with latest chromedriver.

Comment: I tryed in chrome driver it still doesnt work

Comment: I had given one solution couple of months ago, Let me check in my answer list.

Comment: This is in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950700/language-translation-in-selenium-java/68954570#68954570 not sure if it will help you. cause opposite is working for you, only one case is not working when translating from en to different lang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem by `add_argument()`. I tested it with the code you provided and it worked very well.

This is a simple example:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("--lang=fr");
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
prefs = {
        "translate_whitelists": {'en':'fr'},
       "translate":{"enabled":"true"}}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = Edge(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge")
```

**Note**: Modify the EdgeDriver path according to your situation

Answer (score 0):

There are several flavors of English, so instead of simply `en` English you should distinguish between Great Britain English and United States English in case of translating from English.
So, instead of

```py
"translate_whitelists": {'en':'es'}
```

Try this

```py
"translate_whitelists": {'en-GB':'es'}
```

or this

```py
"translate_whitelists": {'en-US':'es'}
```

Comment: I have tryed that it still isnt working. Is the issue from edge?

Comment: Hm, I don't know. I never worked with Edge on Selenium. Only Chrome and Firefox. Sorry